# Express.js custom error handling middleware isn't working for a few errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Custom error handler:

```
export const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (err, _, res) => {
  if (err instanceof HttpError) {
    res.status(err.statusCode).json({
      message: err.message
    });
    return;
  }
  res.status(500).json({
    message: err.message,
  });
};
```

Handler where I throw the error:

```
export const registerHandler: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body as {
    username: string | undefined;
    password: string | undefined;
  };

  if (!username || !password) {
    throw new UnprocessableEntity();
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.register(username, password);
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    res.json({
      user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new BadRequest(error.message);
  }
};
```

The error handler middleware works as expected when everywhere except when it is thrown in catch block of the registerHandler. It's driving me crazy. Can somebody explain why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

middlewares are pipes, in other words functions that runs after another function, so if you want to run an error handler you need to pass the next function to run

```js
export const registerHandler: Handler = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body as {
    username: string | undefined;
    password: string | undefined;
  };

  if (!username || !password) {
// to let express know that the next function to run is an errorhandler you need to pass a parameter to the function next
    return next(new UnprocessableEntity());
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.register(username, password);
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    res.json({
      user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new BadRequest(error.message);
  }
};
```

to create error handlers you need to create a function with 4 parameter
error: the error
req: request
res: response
next: next handler

```js
function errorHandler (error, req, res, next) {
  if (err instanceof HttpError) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
      message: err.message
    });
  }

return next(error);

}
```

for this to work you need to specify your error handlers after all your routes

```js
const app = express()

app.use("/api", apiRoutes());

app.use("/more-routes", moreRoutes());

app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(anotherErrorHandler);
```

Comment: I did apply the error handler middleware after all the routes and other middlewares.

Comment: "_... you need to specify your error handlers after all your routes_" this phrase is a life saver. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*This might not be the exact solution you may be looking for, but it might help.*

The [express js documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)
says:-

- Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error.

So you don't need try and catch at all.

The above code can be written as:-

```js
  export const registerHandler: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body as {
    username: string | undefined;
    password: string | undefined;
  };

  if (!username || !password) {
    throw new UnprocessableEntity();
  }
   
  const user = await User.register(username, password);
  req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
  });
  res.json({
      user,
  });
};
```

If any error occurs in await line, the errorHandler will automatically be called, and you don't have to explicitly throw an error.